# Reformatting a lot of classes

Tags: eclipse, reformatting

I have a lot of reformatting to do in a old Java project.

I have over than 300 different classes created by factories and I would like to automatize changes with a plugin for Eclipse or with a tool.

I need to remove the same parameter for the 300 classes (as Foo class above) and to change mother class name every time.

example:

```
public Foo extends **OldClass** {

    public Foo(A a, **B b**){
        //..
    }

}
```

to

```
public Foo extends newClass {

    public Foo(A a){
        //..
    }

}
```

I would also like to be able to "batch find and replace" a lot of declarations. I mean, I would like to have a tool with a list of replacements (with regex patterns) and just to replace everything in one click.

Do you know how I could do this? I am on a Windows 7 system.

Comment: Excuse me for the indentation, I don't know why It does not work.

Comment: Could you clarify, is it always the same replacement you want to make across all 300 files (e.g. replace 'OldClass' with 'NewClass' 300 times), or is it different across files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Eclipse's Search dialog (Ctrl+H) to do this. Next to the 'Search' button there is a 'Replace' button. This can be used to find every occurrence across multiple files (specifying for example, every filename matching `*.java`), and replace them in a single user action.

[image: eclipse search dialog with replace option]

Once you have configured your search criteria (e.g. " extends OldClass") and search for that, you will be presented with a dialog to enter a replacement value (e.g. " extends NewClass"). Upon pressing 'OK' for that dialog, it will do the search and replace.

[image: replace dialog]

This also allows regular expressions, both in the search and replace (I'm assuming this would allow using regex group captures, but I haven't tested it). It should be possible to apply the same principle to the parameter you also want to remove.

Note that it gets trickier if you only want to modify classes where both `extends OldClass` AND `, B b)` appear, and they can occur independently.

Comment: Yes, but I need to do it for everything I want to change. I would like to batch the search-replace..

Comment: Unless I have a different understanding of 'batch' this should be possible. I am taking it to mean you want to do it for every file in one action (which this allows, it searches across multiple files), if you mean that you want to run it as a separate task, automatically, apologies.

Comment: I don't speak english, maybe my post is not clear :) In the worst case scenario, I will use CTRL + H everytime. thank you!

Comment: No problem, your English will be infinitely better than my $ANY_LANGUAGE_YOU_SPEAK :-)  I've tried to clarify my answer to show that it will work for ALL 300 classes in *a single* search/replace. So it's *not* like a Ctrl+F Find/Replace which works in a single file. Hope that helps. Please do let me know if I am still misunderstanding.

Comment: It could works that way, but patterns regex in the filename does not work?

Comment: So it's not every class that `extends OldClass` you want to do, it's a subset of Java files that you want to match with a regex?

Answer (score 1):

If the current code is not too complex, you can get away with sed, e.g.,

```
find . -type f -iname '*.txt' -exec sed -i 's,this,that,g' {} +
```

Comment: @Pier-alexandreBouchard Under Windows, you can install Cygwin to get access to some neat Linux based file processing tools, including find and sed.

Comment: @ChristianSemrau I am looking for a plugin or a small tool, because I can't install any software on my job's computer